# Simple event listener not working - JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

I have written an increbily simple event listener and yet it comes up with the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null` which suggests it is to do with the id maybe (also it works with `document`?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function message () {
        alert("Hello!");
        }
        var button = document.getElementById('button');
        button.addEventListener('click', message, true);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Click me!" />
</body>
</html>
```

(I know I'm going to feel stupid after this, but I am a JS noob)

Comment: Put the script section at the bottom of your body section right above `</body>` , the element you're referencing was not loaded yet.

Comment: Bingo! but I thought the script went in the head?

Comment: It's best practice to put at the bottom of the body section in most cases - unless you want them to run _before_ the elements are loaded.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

at the time your script executes, the DOM has not been created. you can place your script after the body tags to run it after reading the html - but the better way to do it is by listening for `DOMContentLoaded`.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
function init(){
  function message () {
    alert("Hello!");
  }
  var button = document.getElementById('button');
  button.addEventListener('click', message, true);
};
```

`window.onload = init` works too. I don't like it because it looks to me like one script could overwrite window.onload to be its own init function. (i haven't confirmed that happens or not)

Comment: if `addEventListener` doesn't work, you can set attribute like: `document.getElementById("ID").setAttribute("onclick","javascript:alert('hello');");`

Answer (score 2):

Because this script is executed when body isn't loaded yet. Use onload event, and within it paste your code.