# How do I create a functioning hamburger menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigationbar, hamburger-menu

So I have tried to create a hamburger menu and have faced no luck. Whenever I click on the menu icon, it changes to an 'X' however it does not open the menu. I have been trying for the last couple of days, and have also researched but have found nothing that works.

Here is my HTML code for the navmenu and hamburger icon:

```js
let menu = document.querySelector('#menu-icon');
let navmenu = document.querySelector('.navmenu');

menu.onclick = () => {
  menu.classList.toggle('bx-x');
  navmenu.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
.navmenu {
  display: flex;
}

.navmenu a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  transition: all .42s ease;
}

.navmenu a:hover {
  color: #03A9F4;
}

.nav-icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-icon i {
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
  transition: all .42s ease;
}

.nav-icon i:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  color: #03A9F4;
}

#menu-icon {
  font-size: 35px;
  display: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 10001;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media(max-width: 750px) {
  #menu-icon {
    display: block;
  }
  .navmenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
    right: 0%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 130vh;
    background: #000;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 120px 30px;
    transition: all .42s;
  }
  .navmenu a {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .navmenu.open {
    right: 0%
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="logo"><img src="images/logo5.png" alt="" class="prevent-select"></a>
<ul class="navmenu">
  <li><a href="#" id="prevent-select" class="hover-underline-animation">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="prevent-select" class="hover-underline-animation">Shop</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="hover-underline-animation" id="prevent-select">Sale</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="hover-underline-animation" id="prevent-select">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="hover-underline-animation" id="prevent-select">Policies</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="hover-underline-animation" id="prevent-select">More</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="nav-icon">
  <a href="#" id="prevent-select"><i class='bx bx-search-alt-2'></i></a>
  <div class="dropdown2">
    <button class="dropbtn2">
                        <a href="#" id="prevent-select"><i class='bx bx-user'></i></a>
                    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content2">
      <div class="login">
        <ul>
          <a href="login_register.php" id="prevent-select">Log in/Register</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" id="prevent-select"><i class='bx bx-shopping-bag'></i></a>
  <div class="bx bx-menu" id="menu-icon"></div>
</div>
```

I tried this but it did not work as it had resulted in what I had mentioned above. I basically want it to slide the menu open when I click the hamburger menu icon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple event listener not working - JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717175/simple-event-listener-not-working-js)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as an example

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  menuBtn.classList.toggle('active');
  menu.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
/* Hamburger menu button */

.menu-btn {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.menu-btn span {
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

/* Hamburger menu button animation */

.menu-btn.active span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(10px) rotate(45deg);
}

.menu-btn.active span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu-btn.active span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
}

/* Slide menu */

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 50px 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

/* Slide menu animation */

.menu.active {
  right: 0;
}

.menu.active a:hover {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="menu-btn">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

@MohammedMalek's is a little better than this one, but another example, just in case you're interested

```js
function toggleMenu() {
    document.getElementById("menu").classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
.container{
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hamburger{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.line{
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.line::before{
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: -8px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.line::after{
  content: '';
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 12px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.list{
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.list.active{
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hamburger" onclick="toggleMenu()">
    <div class="line">
    
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="menu" class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also google around and find CSS-only solutions to this problem - I personally find the JS version much easier to deal with, but I'll throw it out there anyways.